# Admob The following classes could not be instantiated:

Tags: admob

I am trying  to add ads in my app but I keep getting error below.  I have Declared com.google.ads.AdActivity in AndroidManifest.xml.
and Set up required network permissions in the manifest.
and added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in libs that's how my main activity looks like

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
 android:paddingRight="5dp"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:background="@drawable/background"
 tools:context="com.breakinggames.myperfectweight.MainActivity">

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY ID HERE"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

this is the error am getting:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data     when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:          org.json.JSONException   at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:142)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)   at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:184)   at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:352)   at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are getting this error in your IDE, not at runtime.

If it is your IDE then you need to tell your IDE where to find the Admob SDK. But I wouldn't worry about it overly. I rarely review Activity layout in the IDE. Deploy it to a device/emulator instead.

NB The latest version of the Admob SDK is shipped with Google Play Services. You should really consider upgrading.